# SQL Client CPU Utilization

Tags: sql, oracle, cpu-usage

Why does my desktop not use all resources when running a SQL query on an external Oracle DB? I can run what is essentially the same query in two ways:

**Method 1** (40% desktop CPU utilization // 2 min. runtime):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 0 AND 100,000
```

**Method 2** (80% desktop CPU utilization // 1 min. runtime):

Open 2 windows in my SQL client and send these two queries at the same time.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 0 AND 50,000

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 50,000 AND 100,000
```

The `EXPLAIN PLAN` for both of these methods are identical. Is **Method 2**'s download quicker because it users more CPU resources than **Method 1**? If so, how can I coerce Method 1 into using more CPU? Or am I totally off-base here? Thank you!

Comment: Your second query is a kind of home-made parallelism: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm and https://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Using-parallel-SQL-to-improve-Oracle-database-performance

Comment: Why should your _desktop_ use resources if you run a query on the _server_?

Comment: second query wouldn't return rows in Oracle.

Comment: @VictorDiLeo thx. Adding parallelsim in a single query with a hint via /*+ parallel */ drastically improves the explain plan time. However, my computer still downloads the results at same speed. Its not a complex query so I don't think it's the servers resources that are the bottleneck. It appears the server is only willing to send me so many rows per second in one query. Any ideas?

Comment: @FlorinGhita made a good point. How are you actually executing this? To your point - other factors are involved, certainly:: a busy server, internet connection, busy laptop, laptop RAM and # of CPUs and so on.

Comment: @FlorinGhita I run both queries separately. More precisely, I open up two query windows in Teradata and run one query in each. Alternatively, I run them in two IPython notebooks at execute them at the same time.

Comment: @VictorDiLeo ^ See above for how I execute both queries. As the query runs,  Teradata tells me how many rows have downloaded, i.e. after a second it'll say maybe 3,032, after two seconds, it'll say maybe 6,159. So I can monitor how fast my computer is downloading/processing the data. Even if I use the `/*+ parallel */` hint, the query results download at ~3,000 rows/sec. When I run multiple queries, each still downloads at ~3,000 rows/sec. So if I use my "home-made parallelism", I can download rows at a rate of (# of queries) * 3,000 rows/sec.

Comment: @VictorDiLeo Given the query does not require many calculations, I feel as if the DB is only willing to send me ~3,000 rows/sec/query and that the only way to increase download speed is to open up multiple query windows and run them simultaneously. What do you think?

Comment: Your question is tagged with Oracle but you just clarified that you're using Teradata. @FloringGhita was right - your use of rowcount wouldn't run in Oracle - but obviously it's fine in TD. Re: 3k rows - yes, it seems a bit slow but I mentioned the other factors involved; some we have control over, others we don't. Also I did a cursory search of ways to improve JDBC/ODBC connection performance but found nothing useful - you could try a more in-depth search if you like. But that wouldn't mitigate a busy server or slow network. I don't have any other ideas at this point.

Comment: @VictorDiLeo thanks for the help. Apologies I should've clarieid I'm querying an oracle database but am doing so using teradatas SQL assistant. Again thanks for your ideas.